# Loading velocity template inside a jar file

Tags: java, templates, jar, classpath, velocity

I have a project where I want to load a velocity template to complete it with parameters. The whole application is packaged as a jar file. What I initially thought of doing was this:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();

   URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/templates/");

   File file = new File(url.getFile());

   ve = new VelocityEngine();
   ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "file");
   ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
   ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_CACHE, "true");

   ve.init();

   VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

   if (properties != null) {
    stringfyNulls(properties);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : properties.entrySet()) {
     context.put(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
    }
   }

   final String templatePath = templateName + ".vm";
   Template template = ve.getTemplate(templatePath, "UTF-8");
   String outFileName = File.createTempFile("report", ".html").getAbsolutePath();
   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(outFileName)));

   template.merge(context, writer);

   writer.flush();
   writer.close();
```

And this works fine when I run it in eclipse. However, once I package the program and try to run it using the command line I get an error because the file could not be found.

I imagine the problem is in this line:

```
ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Because in a jar the absolute file does not exist, since it's inside a zip, but I couldn't yet find a better way to do it.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: for the love of god, highlight the code in your post and click the code button so that its formatted properly! :)

Comment: Are you quite certain that the /templates/ directory is getting exported into your jar? You have to mark it as part of your build settings and stuff.

Comment: didn't known about the code button, thanks. Yes, the templates dir is getting into the jar file.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you want to use resources from classpath, you should use resource loader for classpath:

```
ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath"); 
ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
ve.init();
```

Comment: I will test it! do you know where I can find documentation to each RuntimeContants and its possible values?

Comment: Couldn't make it work, it doesn't find the file in neither eclipse nor in the jar.

Comment: @Rafael: Fixed. `ClasspathResourceLoader` is not registered by default.

Comment: Thanks, it did work when I used this along with the idea presented by ZZ Coder below.

Comment: Works as written with v 1.7.  Thanks.  `        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();

        ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
        ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());

        ve.init();
`

Comment: Also look at ve.evaluate(..) which allows a java.io.Reader to be passed

Comment: It is unfortunate that [Javadocs of ClasspathResourceLoader](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ClasspathResourceLoader.html) wrongly says that resource loader value should be "class" - I tried that and it did not work, only to discover later that it should be "classpath" as mentioned in this answer

Answer (score 24):

Final code, developed using the ideas presented in both answers above:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());

ve.init();

final String templatePath = "templates/" + templateName + ".vm";
InputStream input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(templatePath);
if (input == null) {
    throw new IOException("Template file doesn't exist");
}

InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

if (properties != null) {
    stringfyNulls(properties);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : properties.entrySet()) {
        context.put(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
    }
}

Template template = ve.getTemplate(templatePath, "UTF-8");
String outFileName = File.createTempFile("report", ".html").getAbsolutePath();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(outFileName)));

if (!ve.evaluate(context, writer, templatePath, reader)) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to convert the template into html.");
}

template.merge(context, writer);

writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a great deal! Might be that my adapation works just a bit different, but using VelocityEngine#evaluate(...), I could leave out the instantiation of the Template and the call to Template#merge(...)

Comment: works like a charm. The RuntimeInstance solved my problem allowing me to load the template in my bundle. Best solution for OSGI

Comment: This solution worked well, except I did not need the merge part at the end.

Answer (score 10):

Unless JAR is exploded, you can't read the resource in JAR as file. Use an input stream.

See following code snippets,

```
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    if (input == null) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("Template file " +
                fileName + " doesn't exist");           
    }

    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);            
        Writer writer = null;

        try {
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output);        

            // Merge template
            if (!engine.evaluate(context, writer, fileName, reader)) 
                ......
```

Answer (score 2):

To make Velocity look for the templates in classpath:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class",ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
ve.init();
```

Comment: I think you're a bit late to the party.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have an old version, this is the only thing that worked for me

```
ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class"); 
ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", 
ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
```