# Resources folder in a Java EE application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I'm developing a simple mail sender as **Java EE** application.

The project structure is shown as follows:

[image: Java EE app proj structure]

To properly setup email contents, I need to read the `*.vm` files placed inside the resource folder, that I supposed to have as path `classpath:/templates/mail/*.vm` (as with **Spring**)... But my supposition is wrong!

1. Which is the right path to use?
2. Should I have to use the `META-INF` folder? Is this solution more
   *java-ee-compliant*? In that case, where have I to put the `META-INF` folder inside my project structure?

---

**Update:**

I packaged the project as `.war`, then I putted the files in:

```
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/templates/mail/
```

Then:

```
org.apache.velocity.Template t = myVelocityEngine.getTemplate("classpath:/templates/mail/account_to_confirm.vm",
                    "UTF-8");
```

Nonetheless, the app returns an error at runtime:

```
Unable to find resource 'classpath:/templates/mail/account_to_confirm.vm'
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Just to better understand:**

Supposing that I'd like to deploy this app as `jar` (removing the servlet class, of course): in that case, should I have to edit the folder layout in order to still use the same path into the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is due to the prefix `classpath:`: where did you find that you have to use it?

You might find useful understanding how to initialize `VelocityEngine` reading [Loading velocity template inside a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931516/loading-velocity-template-inside-a-jar-file) and how [Configuring Resource Loaders in Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/developer-guide.html#resourceloaders).

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use Classloader.getResourceAsStream("templates/mail/*.vm"); or similar getResourceAsURL method.

If not, take a look at [where files from resources are placed inside WAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html). In your case, the file should be in /WEB-INF/classes/templates/mail .

Comment: I'd like to deploy this project as jar. I defined a servlet just to test the code.

Comment: in such case, the files would be located in / of JAR, and classpath would be /META-INF/classes (as far as I remember, please use ZIP to verify it). You can put META-INF directory in your resources, it's content would be merged with META-INF generated during compilation

Comment: Should I to put the `META-INF` folder in `/src/main/resources`? In that case, which path have I to use in my code to retrieve the files?

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use the template. Please, post the code fragment you are using and I'll try to answer. But the classpath:path you suggested looks correct for given setup (but only if you package it as a JAR file - if you package it as a WAR file, the directories layout is different, maybe that's the problem here? have you tested it as a JAR, not a WAR?)

Comment: Now, I'm packaging the project as war in order to properly run it on my Application Server, thus probably I'm using a bad directory layout. In other words, in this moment I have to use webapp folder layout, then  archive folder layout.

Comment: For war testing it'd be fastest to copy the resources into /WEB-INF/classes directory using for example http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html.
You can also change the directory layout and put everything you have in main/resources/ into main/resources/WEB-INF/classes/ directory. This should help, but remember to revert the changes when going back to JAR packaging

Comment: I've put my files in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/templates/mail, but at runtime, the app returns this error: "Unable to find resource 'templates/mail/account_to_confirm.vm'"